# Prometheus one to one metric merge with missing label values

Tags: promql

I have two metrics I want to add together, but not all the labels are present in the two metrics. I want to treat the missing label values as zeros.

For example:

- `metric1` has label `instance` with time series `(a, b)`
- `metric2` has label `instance` with time series `(b, c)`

I want `metric1 + metric2` so that I get:

- `metric1{instance="a"}`
- `metric1{instance="b"} + metric2{instance="b"}`
- `metric2{instance="c"}`

But instead, I only get the second one and am missing the other two that don't have matching label values.  (In reality, I don't know ahead of time what label values are in the two metrics.)

How can I merge these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `or` solution in the other answer looks good and may be useful in other situations, it explodes pretty quickly, as it turns out I actually need `sum(metric1) by (instance)` , etc. for each of the metrics, and the repeated use on each side of the `or` makes that pretty long and ugly.

I found a better method that wasn't obvious as long as the `metric{instance=}` syntax was the focus.

It turns out a simpler way to do this, refactoring the whole expression, is

```
sum({__name__=~"metric1|metric2"}) by (instance)
```

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use operator [`or`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators)

Your query will look like this:

```
metric1 + metric2 or metric1 or metric2
```

Operator `or` evaluates both parts and returns unique set of labels, prioritizing left side.

In your case:

- `metric1 + metric2` returns only `{instance="b"}`,
- `metric1` returns `{instance="a"}` and `{instance="b"}`,
- `metric2` returns `{instance="b"}` and `{instance="c"}`

Then first operator `or` returns `{instance="b"}` with value of sum, and `{instance="a"}` with value of `metric1`. Second `or` adds to result set `{instance="c"}` with value of `metric2`.

Comment: I tried `or` but not this way...interesting!